# Web scraping for company logos from domain urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working on web scraping from domain urls for scraping company logos using python.

```
import requests

url = "https://logo.clearbit.com/shopify.com"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

However, it just renders the image but I need the source url for the logo.

please help!

Thanks

Comment: ```from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldata = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepsi')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img')

for item in images:
    img = 'https:' + item['src']
    # print(img)
    if 'logo' in img:
        print(img)```

Comment: I am trying web scrap company logos from theor domains and result should be also in urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `requests_html` library....

`pip install requests-html`

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepsi')
selector = response.html.xpath("//img[contains(@alt,'logo')]/@src")[0]
print(selector)
```

output:

```
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/Pepsi_logo_2014.svg/140px-Pepsi_logo_2014.svg.png
```